# Please let me know how to add update button feature to in this jquery code

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jqgrid

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
        <%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags" %>
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
            <html>

                <head>
                    <title>AJAX JSP PAGE</title>
                    <sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css"
                    type="text/css" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.darkblue.css"
                    type="text/css" />
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase-3.5.0/jqwidgets/jqxtabs.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document)
                            .ready(function () {
                            // prepare the data

                            $('#jqxTabs')
                                .jqxTabs({
                                width: 550,
                                height: 150
                            });

                            $("#myButton")
                                .jqxButton({
                                width: '280px',
                                height: '35px',
                                theme: 'darkblue'
                            });


                            var input1Val = "";
                            var input2Val = "";
                            var input3Val = "";


                            $("#input1")
                                .keyup(function () {

                                input1Val = $("#input1")
                                    .val()
                                myfunction();
                            });


                            function myfunction() {

                                var source = {
                                    datatype: "json",
                                    datafields: [{
                                        name: 'name',
                                        type: 'string'
                                    }, {
                                        name: 'age',
                                        type: 'number'
                                    }, {
                                        name: 'gender',
                                        type: 'string'
                                    }, {
                                        name: 'studentId',
                                        type: 'string'
                                    }, {
                                        name: 'homeAddress',
                                        type: 'string'
                                    }, {
                                        name: 'area',
                                        type: 'string'
                                    }, {
                                        name: 'fathersName',
                                        type: 'string'
                                    }, {
                                        name: 'button',
                                        type: 'string'
                                    }, ],

                                    id: 'id',
                                    url: 'callAJax.action?t=' + Math.random() + '&name=' + input1Val,
                                    async: true,
                                    sortcolumn: 'name',
                                    sortdirection: 'asc',
                                };

                                var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
                                    loadComplete: function (data) {},
                                    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {}
                                });

                                $("#jqxgrid")
                                    .jqxGrid({

                                    width: 900,
                                    height: 450,
                                    sortable: true,
                                    filterable: true,
                                    altrows: true,
                                    source: dataAdapter,
                                    columns: [{
                                        text: 'name',
                                        datafield: 'name',
                                        width: 100,
                                        cellsformat: 'c2'
                                    }, {
                                        text: 'Age',
                                        datafield: 'age',
                                        width: 50
                                    }, {
                                        text: 'Gender',
                                        datafield: 'gender',
                                        width: 80
                                    }, {
                                        text: 'Student Id',
                                        datafield: 'studentId',
                                        width: 120
                                    }, {
                                        text: 'Home Address',
                                        datafield: 'homeAddress',
                                        width: 180
                                    }, {
                                        text: 'Area',
                                        datafield: 'area',
                                        width: 100,
                                        cellsalign: 'right'
                                    }, {
                                        text: 'Fathers Name',
                                        datafield: 'fathersName',
                                        width: 120
                                    }, {
                                        text: 'Print',
                                        datafield: 'button',
                                        width: 100
                                    }, {
                                        text: 'Id',
                                        datafield: 'id',
                                        width: 50
                                    }, ],
                                    gridComplete: function () {

                                        alert("gridcomplete()");
                                    },
                                });

                                $('#events')
                                    .jqxPanel({
                                    width: 300,
                                    height: 80,
                                    theme: theme
                                });

                                $("#jqxgrid")
                                    .bind("sort", function (event) {
                                    $("#events")
                                        .jqxPanel('clearcontent');

                                    var sortinformation = event.args.sortinformation;
                                    var sortdirection = sortinformation.sortdirection.ascending ? "ascending" : "descending";
                                    if (!sortinformation.sortdirection.ascending && !sortinformation.sortdirection.descending) {
                                        sortdirection = "null";
                                    }

                                    var eventData = "Triggered 'sort' event <div>Column:" + sortinformation.sortcolumn + ", Direction: " + sortdirection + "</div>";
                                    $('#events')
                                        .jqxPanel('prepend', '<div style="margin-top: 5px;">' + eventData + '</div>');
                                });



                                $('#clearsortingbutton')
                                    .jqxButton({
                                    height: 25,
                                    theme: theme
                                });
                                $('#sortbackground')
                                    .jqxCheckBox({
                                    checked: true,
                                    height: 25,
                                    theme: theme
                                });
                                // clear the sorting.
                                $('#clearsortingbutton')
                                    .click(function () {
                                    $("#jqxgrid")
                                        .jqxGrid('removesort');
                                });
                                // show/hide sort background
                                $('#sortbackground')
                                    .bind('change', function (event) {
                                    $("#jqxgrid")
                                        .jqxGrid({
                                        showsortcolumnbackground: event.args.checked
                                    });
                                });

                            }

                        });
                    </script>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <center>
                        <br />
                        <button id="button1" name="button">Click to make Jquery Ajax request</button>
                        <br />Populates data here.
                        <br/>
                        <table id="list2"></table>
                        <div id="pager2"></div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <input type="button" name="button" id='myButton' onclick="setStart();"
                        value="Click to make Javascript Ajax request" />
                        <br/>Javascript Ajax call output
                        <br/>
                        <div id="intValueDiv" style="color: red;font-weight: bold"></div>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
                            <input id="resizeButton" type="button" value="Auto Resize Columns" />
                            <br/>
                            <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" />
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
                    </center>
                </body>

            </html>
```

I am able load data dynamically. But Now I want to

1) Add button to each row.
2) When clicked, want to access a row values and make an ajax call.

Could anyone, please let me know, the changes required.

Please re-post complete code. That would really help very much.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I used this info here http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?(arctic)#demos/jqxgrid/popupediting.htm successfully. I saw what it did and then looked at View Source to finish learning how. Took me about 30 min. Not bad to get it all done.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. If you have an answer to the original question, then you should include it here.